# Campy Chorus Shifter

Tags: campagnolo

I just bought a used bike but I'm unsure of the condition of the brifters (Campy Chorus 10 alloys). When set up, the brake lever is pulled outwards by the brake cable, away from the shifting pedal. As a result when the bike is stationary, the shifters look like this. I don't think this is right... does anybody have any tips on if this is how they're supposed to be or if there's a broken component in the shifters causing this?

Thanks,
Chris!

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Chris. The image is not loading for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's this horizontal pin on the brake lever next to the hoods. It's meant to open the brakes for easier wheel changes as Campy brakes don't have release levers on the calipers. It seems be in the 'released' position. Pull the lever and push the pin from the side that's sticking out. See if it resolves your problem.
If yours brake pads are already very close to the rims you will probably have to adjust the cable.

Comment: You can see [in this video](https://youtu.be/bufAqVKyJfo?t=36s) how the brake is released (pin pushed to the exterior). Push it in the interior of the bike to lock it back in.

Comment: You definitely don't want to ride your bike with the levers this way. It greatly diminishes the amount of braking power you have.